# 'Yarn install' cause 'trouble with network connection'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, yarnpkg, react-on-rails

```
yarn install v0.21.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://github.com/igorklopov/node-resolve.git: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 140399640340352:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:\n".
```

First i thought that this may be proxy issue
So I've added my corporate proxy settings:

```
yarn config set proxy http://proxy.dvfu.ru:3128
yarn config set https-proxy https://proxy.dvfu.ru:3128
```

But nothing happened, still have the error above.

Comment: Check out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638486/8066713 This worked for myself and many others.

Answer (score 12):

Try below this three commands. Its worked for me.

1. yarn config delete proxy
2. npm config rm proxy
3. npm config rm https-proxy

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved by following steps:

Run the terminal command

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `set http_proxy=`
3. `set https_proxy=`
4. `yarn config delete proxy`
5. `npm config rm https-proxy`
6. `npm config rm proxy`
7. Restart your terminal
8. `yarn`
9. `yarn –-network-timeout 100000`
10. Restart your terminal.

it worked for me.

Comment: can't test it now, but thanks for your participation