# Yarn - There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying

Tags: yarnpkg

I have been trying to do the quickstart guide for react native, but kept getting this error

```
There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

My connection works just fine.

Comment: I just got this this error when creating a new Vuejs project. My internet speed is 4mb/s and I'm not behind any proxy. The problem was Vuejs was using another registry `taobao.org` which is very slow. I just deleted the file `.vuerc` from my home folder and make sure I selected `no` when Vuejs prompted to use the `taobao.org` registry.

Comment: In my case, despite passing `--network-timeout 100000`, turning off Windows Defender, clearing proxy settings, disabling IPv6, and running `yarn cache clean --force` I get "There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying..." a few times followed by:
`error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@electron-forge/template-typescript/-/template-typescript-6.0.0-beta.57.tgz: read ECONNRESET"` though I can copy/paste this link into a web browser and quickly download without problems. `npm install` also works... ug

Comment: For me the problem was with yarn, i do not know the problem but switching npm just worked.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

This happens when your network is too slow or the package being installed is too large, and Yarn just assumes it's a network problem.
Try increasing Yarn network timeout:

```
yarn add <yourPackage> --network-timeout 100000
```

Comment: @SunilGarg doesn't matter what package name. `--network-timeout` is just a yarn flag that tells it to set the network timeout to that particular value. This can be `yarn add react --network-timeout 100000`, `yarn add @angular/core --network-timeout 100000` or just `yarn --network-timeout 100000`

Comment: I kept forgetting to add the `--network-timeout` switch when running `yarn`, so I added an alias for it to my `~/.bashrc` file just after the `yarn` `PATH` modification as follows: `alias yarn='yarn --network-timeout 100000'`

Comment: For people like me and @PaulMEdwards, I added another answer that does the network-timeout setting, but sets it globally always. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69038041/756329

Comment: another useful option is --network=host. In my case is was: docker build --network=host --progress=plain .

Comment: May not be an ideal answer, but I just changed from company wifi to mobile hotspot, and it worked. It also worked in the past ...

Comment: `yarn install --network-timeout=300000` to install all the packages of the project

Comment: @MsA not ideal but only works ;) Can't getting how it works, but works. My WiFi connection was really fast 200MB/s, but it was too slow for yarn. When I switched to slowest mobile, yarn was satisfied. Thanks

Answer (score 105):

Deleting the yarn.lock file and rerunning "yarn install" worked for me.

Comment: This gave me an error using docker-compose build --no-cache: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/yarn.lock" not found: not found

Comment: should never ever delete lock files. This defeats the purpose of having them in first place.

Answer (score 41):

I got this issue because I was working within my company internal network and proxy needed to be set.

```
$ yarn config set proxy http://my_company_proxy_url:port
$ yarn config set https-proxy http://localhost:3128

example $ yarn config set https-proxy http://proxy.abc.com:8080
```

Comment: Sometimes you might need to pass credentials like:                                                 $ yarn config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy:port

Answer (score 38):

```
yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g
```

Often, your error is caused by hitting the network connection time limit, and yarn simply reports there is "trouble with your network connection".

The line of code at the top of my answer sets the global yarn network timeout to 10 minutes.

Having a long network timeout is probably okay, because yarn uses caches and if it's big and you don't have it, you probably want it to just go ahead and take the time to download.

Comment: Thanks. This was `yarn add @tabler/icons-react` for me. Hope that SEO help someones in the future.

Answer (score 37):

**Simple working solution (right way of doing it):**

Looks like yarn was trying to connect via a proxy. The following worked for me:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

[Source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4890#issuecomment-377867471)

Answer (score 37):

Turning off "real time protection" with windows defender fixed it for me.

Sucks but it appears the checks are too much for yarn to handle.

Comment: Same issue running react-native init on Windows 10 ^^ this fixed it

Comment: Its better to exclude certain directories in windows defender than turning it off each time

Comment: @Yashas If defender turning off each time is concern then there is option to disable it parentally from windows regedit

Comment: That worked, after disabling real-time protection in security, I was able to install the packages with yarn.

Answer (score 31):

1. Could be that your network speed is too slow and timeout is relatively short, you can set `yarn install --network-timeout=30000`
2. If you still have the error, could be solved by proxy, `vim ~/.yarnrc` and add useful proxy setting.

Comment: Hi Guys this command really works when you are getting network connection problem in your Mac while doing yarn install even your network connection is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

The following helped me

```
yarn config delete https-proxy
yarn config delete proxy
```

they set your https-proxy and proxy values to undefined. My https-proxy was set to localhost. Check that proxy and https-proxy config values are undefined by using the following

```
yarn config get https-proxy
yarn config get proxy
```

Answer (score 13):

Could be a proxy issue. Run the command below to delete the proxy.

```
yarn config delete proxy
```

Answer (score 9):

The large package involved often can be Material Design Icons.

Check if you make use of the Material Design Fonts `material-design-icons` in your `package.json` and remove it!

`material-design-icons` is too big to handle and you should only use `material-design-icons-fonts` if you only need them.

https://medium.com/@henkjan_47362/just-a-short-notice-for-whomever-is-searching-for-hours-like-i-did-a741d0cd167b

Comment: Spot on the money for me! I ended up adding separately and it didn't timeout.

Answer (score 7):

Got the exact issue when trying `yarn install`

```
yarn install --network-timeout 100000
```

Just using this didn't solve my problem. I had to install only ~5 packages at a time. So I ran `yarn install` multiple times with only few dependencies in the package.json at a time.

Hope this helpful

Answer (score 3):

In short, this is caused when yarn is having network problems and is unable to reach the registry. This can be for any number of reasons, but in all cases, the error is the same, so you might need to try a bunch of different solutions.

**Reason 1: Outdated Proxy Settings**

This will throw the "network connection" error if you are connected to a network that uses a proxy and you did not update yarn configs with the correct proxy setting.

You can start running the below commands to check what the current proxy configs are set to:

```
yarn config get https-proxy
yarn config get proxy
```

If the proxy URLs returned are not what you expect, you just need to run the following commands to set the correct ones:

```
yarn config set https-proxy <proxy-url>
yarn config set proxy <proxy-url>
```

Similarly, if you have previously set up the proxy on yarn but are no longer using a network connection that needs a proxy. In this case, you just need to do the opposite and delete the proxy config:

```
yarn config delete https-proxy
yarn config delete proxy
```

**Reason 2: Incorrect Domain name resolution**

This will throw the "network connection" error if for whatever reason your machine cannot resolve your yarn registry URL to the correct IP-address. This would usually only happen if you (or your organization) are using an in-house package registry and the ip-address to the registry changes.

In this case, the issue is not with yarn but rather with your machine. You can solve this by updating your `hosts` file (for mac users, this should be found in '/etc/hosts') with the correct values, by adding a mapping as follows:

```
<ip-address> <registry-base-url>
```

example:

```
10.0.0.1 artifactory.my.fancy.organiza.co.za
```

Answer (score 2):

When I want to use `yarn` I have above error, but there is not any error with `npm`, for this situation you can install `react project` from `npm`

```
npx create-react-app app --use-npm
```

Comment: Not sure if this has any unintended side effects but it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working within a **docker** environment or elsewhere that might need a different approach where you are not modifying the installation process, try adding a file named `.yarnrc` in the root of the project with the problem (where your package.json resides) and in that file write:

```
network-timeout 600000
```

Docker will still run without modifying the docker-compose.yml file and you get the timeout solution.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while attempting `yarn outdated`. In my case, a few of the packages in my project were hosted in a private registry within the company network. I didn't realize my VPN was disconnected so it was initially confusing to see the error message whilst I was still able to browse the web.

It becomes quite obvious for those patient enough to wait out all five retry attempts. I, however, ctrl-c'd after three attempts...

Answer (score 1):

Turn off or disable your antivirus before run this command. I am also facing same issue than i disable quick heal antivirus and it is works.

```
create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found a reference to a defunct registry in my ~/.yarnrc file

When I removed that the error went away

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the yarn-lock file, doing a yarn cache clean and then a yarn solved my issue

Comment: The idea behind the lock file is to have reproducible installs across different machines. So one should keep in mind that this might have (maybe small) side effects.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install
```

worked for me (but my project was built with yarn)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30247394)

Comment: Nothing worked for me, so I am back to `npm install`

Comment: This works for me too, my project was built with yarn, but after a long time, now yarn reports network error.

Answer (score 1):

Adding option --network=host was the solution in my case.

> docker build --network=host --progress=plain .

Comment: That's it, in my case had to set the `docker-compose` network to `driver: host`, thanks a lot 

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was Window's real-time protection which was causing the issue. Turn off the `Real-time protection` till your package is installed. Then turn it ON.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened in my case trying to run `yarn install`.

My project is a set of many sub-projects.
After a couple of retries, it showed a socket-timeout error log:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://<myregitry>/directory/-/subProject1-1.0.2.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
```

I cloned `subProject1` separately, did `yarn install` on it and linked it with main project.

I was able to continue with my command on main project after that.
Once done, I unlinked the `subProject1` and did a final `yarn install --force` which was success.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to run yarn install - i use WSL with ubuntu distro, the following command fixed it,

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late answer but here are some possible reasons:

- If you are behind a proxy you may need to configure .npmrc if you are using *npm* or .yarnrc if you are using *yarn*
- If proxy is well setup, you may need remove **yarn.lock** or **package-lock.json** and re-run `npm i` or `yarn`

Comment: it was useful. I removed .npmrc and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but adding VS Code to the Firewall Exception List has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but my case is totally different. I am on Linux, and I get this error because I had a service nginx status off.

Answer (score 0):

Check your nvm is used for the current project path

Comment: Then how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

turning off VPN solved the issue for me

Also check if you have enough space for installing new packages, I also didnt have enough space...

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this issue, none of which worked for me. After giving it some thought I realized I had just updated Docker. As Hail Mary I tried running Docker Desktop in administrator mode and to my surprise that solved the issue.

I'm not too sure why this was all of a sudden a requirement for my machine but if you find yourself clutching at straws give this a shot.