# ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error while yarn install command

Tags: javascript, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm having troubles with yarn but only on one computer.

When I run `yarn install` some packages can't be downloaded and I have this error : ESOCKETTIMEDOUT :

[image]

At first I just thought that there were some issues at the repository but:

1. I can download the package through a web browser
2. I didn't have any issue with another computer

I tried with the latest version of yarn too and still have this error.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DKst.png):

Answer (score 19):

It's network problem 
I think you use the default timeout

A solution will be in `.yarnrc` file add that line

```
 network-timeout 600000
```

if `600000` didn't work try to increase and if `.yarnrc` not there then create it

Comment: already tried that and didn't help. I doubt it's a network issue since it works with another computer

Comment: it's a network issue for the default timeout set in that computer

Comment: @Kasmir try that `yarn add YourPackageHere --network-timeout 600000`

Comment: it's been a long time and I forgot to answer. if I set to 10 minutes as you said it works. I didn't set a high enough value in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to the `.yarnrc` solution is to provide the network timeout param to `yarn install`:

```
yarn install --network-timeout 600000
```

(found it [here](https://forums.balena.io/t/esockettimedout-on-yarn-install-during-local-push/328990), it's also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55331023/624597))

Answer (score 2):

I hope you've found a solution for yourself.

Today, I'm having the same problem. A work around I needed to try is to set a new timeout for yarn like our friend stated before.

I made it by running the following command in my project root:

```
yarn config set network-timeout 300000
```

It's easier to set your parameter time out instead of creating a new file with your yarn configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue recently in setting up a new project. It got solved for me using the command :-

`yarn install --force --network-timeout 1000000`