# Salesforce, lwc local development server crashing

Tags: salesforce

Starting LWC Local Development.
Username: test-lgcvzacysqx3@example.com
Api Version: 49.0

[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> https://ability-customization-2906-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events: [ 'proxyReq', 'error', 'close' ]
cp: no such file or directory: /Users/admin/Desktop/suman/force-app/main/default/staticresources/*
cp: no such file or directory: /Users/admin/Desktop/suman/force-app/main/default/contentassets/*
LWR6003: Listening on :3333
Server up on http://localhost:3333
LWR6000: Created version hash "f5aff7264b"
LWR6001: Writing /Users/admin/Desktop/suman/.localdevserver/webruntime/custom-component/f617504cf1/dev/en-GB/c/myfirstLwc.js...
LWR6001: Writing /Users/admin/Desktop/suman/.localdevserver/webruntime/custom-component/f617504cf1/dev/en-GB/c/myfirstLwc.js...
CLIError: timed out
at Object.error (/Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/errors/index.js:28:15)
at /Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:25:66
at async flush (/Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:121:9) {
oclif: { exit: 2 },
code: undefined
}
CLIError: timed out
at Object.error (/Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/errors/index.js:28:15)
at /Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:25:66
at async flush (/Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:121:9) {
oclif: { exit: 2 },
code: undefined
}
LWR6004: Server is shutdown
Error: timed out
at Object.error (/Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/errors/index.js:28:15)
at /Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:25:66
at async flush (/Users/admin/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js:121:9)
10:01:49.554 sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start
ended with exit code 1

Error: The local development server exited unexpectedly with code 1.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar error today

But somehow made it running using the below solution

Open the below path

> C:/Users/**UserName**/AppData/Local/sfdx/client/7.163.0-ea5a9c6/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux

And edit the **async flush()** method in the `index.js` file
from **10000** to **600000**

```
await timeout(flush(), 600000);
```

Hope this helps.

found some articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845756/esockettimedout-error-while-yarn-install-command) for help