# getting an error while creating react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Hi guys Am getting an error  while creating an react app don't know what's going on wrong please try to fix my error and also tell me what should i do?

> note :: my internet in working

```
F:\React JS>npx create-react-app project

Creating a new React app in F:\React JS\project.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.10
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "F:\\React JS\\project\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd F:\React JS\project has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Comment: Did you try to turn your computer off and on again?

Comment: yes i tried it but its not working

Comment: Is your network slow, or are you behind a proxy? You might have some luck running through these answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508364/yarn-there-appears-to-be-trouble-with-your-network-connection-retrying

Comment: Do you have good internet connectivity?

Comment: yes i have good internet

Comment: Did you try to uninstall npm and then reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

You need the latest version of yarn, npm, and node. Please make sure they are up to date.

You can try like this

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

This will install npm globally (the meaning of put -g) and the latest version.

```
nvm install node
```

nvm installs Node.js and npm manages packages.

Finally `npm install -g yarn`

This might work perfectly if you have a good internet connection.

Comment: okay i will try

Comment: i tried it all method that mentioned above but its not working You can checkout my all updated version https://ibb.co/tmyyB4M