# Material UI error An unexpected error occurred:

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to add the package from Material-UI, but show me this error.
somebody help, please!
´
[image]

> warning ..\package.json: No license field
> [1/4] Resolving packages...´
> [2/4] Fetching packages...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> error An unexpected error occurred:´

Comment: Is your WiFi okay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yarn - There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508364/yarn-there-appears-to-be-trouble-with-your-network-connection-retrying)

Answer (score 0):

> There appears to be trouble with your network connection

It says it' related to your Internet. Just check it :)