# Info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying

Tags: strapi, azure-webapps

I am facing this issue since couple of days.
I was trying to host strapi on azure with azure postgres DB.
while deploying to web app from visual studio code it throws
“info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying…”.

It tries to Fetch Packages and throws that info couple of times and throws following error:
error An unexpected error occurred: “https://registry.yarnpkg.com/date-fns/-/date-fns-2.24.0.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT”.
I works fine locally.
I have tried every solution on the internet but nothing seems to work[image]

Project folder structure:
[image]

I have tried everything from
[Yarn - There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508364/yarn-there-appears-to-be-trouble-with-your-network-connection-retrying)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before, I was using the wrong npm registry.

So, basically, paste it on your terminal:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

If you have a `.npmrc` file make sure to point it to `npm`, like this:

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

Comment: How to setup this in Azure? I have put it in .npmrc, but Azure still tries to download from https://registry.npmjs.org when I deploy from vscode.

Btw, shouldn't the line in  .npmrc file be:

registry=https://registry.npm.pkg.github.com

?