# Azure local git - Problem deploying Node.js app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a Node.js (Strapi v.4 to be specific) app to Azure App Services from a local git repo. However, I am getting the following message `remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...` when I run `git push azure master` from my local repo.

See below for a more detailed output:

```
remote: yarn install v1.22.10
remote: [1/5] Validating package.json...
remote: [2/5] Resolving packages...
remote: [3/5] Fetching packages...
remote: ..........................
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
remote: .
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
remote: .....
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
remote: ..........
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
remote: ..........
remote: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

Would trying to push the repo from an internal company network be the cause of this error? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847604/18365823) makes me so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by removing the node_modules folder and .lock file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).