# Yarn install timeout on Azure App Service (Oryx)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, yarnpkg, oryx

When using the Azure App Service through vscode, when deploying to a webapp. The Oryx operations may fail because of a timeout during the installation of packages with Yarn with the message "There appears to be trouble with your network connection."

```bash
[…]
9:18:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Using Node version:
9:18:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: v16.14.2
9:18:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Using Yarn version:
9:18:57 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: 1.22.15
9:18:57 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Running 'yarn install --prefer-offline'...
9:18:58 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: yarn install v1.22.15
9:18:59 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: [1/4] Resolving packages...
9:19:01 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: [2/4] Fetching packages...
9:20:31 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[…]
9:25:26 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[…]
9:28:53 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: /bin/bash -c 'oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 16 -i /tmp/8da895c5510e8c2 -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log  | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log ; exit $PIPESTATUS '
9:28:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Generating summary of Oryx build
9:28:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Parsing the build logs
9:28:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Found 0 issue(s)
9:28:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Build Summary :
9:28:54 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: ===============
9:28:55 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Errors (0)
9:28:55 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Warnings (0)
9:28:55 PM Azure-App-Service-Bug-Backend: Deployment Failed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure team resolved this issue, I created the wiki for future reference.

Linked to https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4890

Linked to [Yarn - There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508364/yarn-there-appears-to-be-trouble-with-your-network-connection-retrying)

To circumvent the issue during the Oryx operations, you must create a configuration file that will specify a longer timeout when downloading packages.

At the time Oryx uses Yarn V1.22.15

Create a [.yarnrc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarnrc/) file at the project root
add `network-timeout 240000` to the file

You can change 240000 to any value that is appropriate.

In case Oryx updates Yarn to 2.x, the file to be created will be named [.yarnrc.yml](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#httpTimeout) and the value to append will be `httpTimeout: 240000`

Comment: thanks for this - i was scratching my head why the nodejs app can't deploy to azure app service for the last 30min!