# tunneling socket could not be established | yarn create next-app

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg

When I try to look up for this kind of problem, most are because they were using a proxy, but I don't. I get this error on my git bash:

```
$ yarn create next-app firstapp
yarn create v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/create-next-app: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8889".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

I'm following the guide on nextjs.org. I thought it was due to my bad connection, but when I try it another time, I still get the same error.

My Node.js is at v14.17.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yarn - There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508364/yarn-there-appears-to-be-trouble-with-your-network-connection-retrying)