# How to fix yarn causing trouble while creating react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I want to create a react app with `create-react-app react-app` and I get the following error

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.13.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning react-scripts > jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/314
2
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/req
uest/request/issues/3142
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > strip-comments > babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: co
re-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3
.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@svgr/webpack/-/webpack-4.3.3.tgz: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EC
ONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3128".


Aborting installation.
```

I am working behind a company proxy but this is setup, I can install packages via npm for example `npm i -g create-react-app`, `npm i winston`, etc. without a problem.
I googled the problem and tried something like:

```
yarn install --network-timeout 1000000
```

I configured the npm proxy and the yarn proxy but this doestn work either.
If I try something like this: ['Yarn install' cause 'trouble with network connection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061045/yarn-install-cause-trouble-with-network-connection)
I cant even use npm install anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This only seems to be the problem with your internet connection.  
If you are on windows try deleting the temporary files and restarting your router. 
 
If that doesn't solve your problem then consider restarting your machine. Maybe it may help.